# Why do I get different instances of the same singleton in different modules?

Tags: python, module, singleton, instances

I have 2 files that print a singleton instance, but I get two different instances.

I'm using Singleton code from [Gary Robinson](http://www.garyrobinson.net/2004/03/python_singleto.html).

Here are the files:

### test.py

```
from singleton import Singleton
import untitled

class A(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A.getInstance()
    print a
    untitled.print_a()
```

### untitled.py

```
def print_a():
    import test
    print test.A.getInstance()
```

...and here is the output of `python test.py`

```
<__main__.A object at 0xaea270>
<test.A object at 0xaea3f0>
```

Can someone please explain to me what is happening (apparently at the module level) that is causing this behavior?

Comment: What's in the `test2` module? Does test2 import the `A` from `test.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get two singletons is due to the way the modules are being imported.  When you execute test.py from the command line, it is not known as `test`, it is `__main__`.  An entry is added to `sys.modules` under the name `__main__`, and execution proceeds.  When untitled imports test, `sys.modules` is examined, no module named `test` is found, so test.py is executed again to import it.  As a result, the class definition for `A` is executed twice, producing two distinct classes.  The Singleton implementation therefore considers them distinct, and produces two instances.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Ned! This is exactly the type of explanation I was looking for. I find it a little surprising. So a Python program where another module imports the `__main__` module by it's modulename `m`, `m` will be imported twice. Therefore using classmethods to create a static class as @jsbueno suggested is a moot point given what I was doing.

Comment: The best way to protect yourself against this problem is to keep as much code as possible out of the main file, or to pass objects explicitly instead of re-importing the main file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need singletons for, but just taking a look at that "singleton mixin" you pointed too reminded me of an old joke chain-email showing the various stages of a programer (d)evolution, with various examples of a hello world program. On that e-mail, the low-point was the "enterprise class senior program" which developed a client server system, implementing various patterns, in order to write "Hello World".

On the same text, the high point, was the "master hacker", which implemented Hello world with a sngle line:
echo Hello World!

So,
most likely all you need is just a class from which you use the class and not its instances. it will behave like a singleton for all purposes. If you want to make shure it is not instantiated, just raise an exception on the **new** method:

```
class SimpleSingleton(object):
    @classmethod
    def my_singleton_method(cls,):
         pass
    def __new__(cls):
         raise TypeError("Cannot be instantiated")
```

Comment: Sure, I could use a static class (and I appreciate the suggestion), but that wasn't really the question.